# Scala naming convention for "setters" on immutable objects

Tags: scala, conventions

I do not know what to call my "setters" on immutable objects?

For a mutable object Person, setters work like this:

```
class Person(private var _name: String) {
  def name = "Mr " + _name
  def name_=(newName: String) {
    _name = newName
  }
}

val p = new Person("Olle")
println("Hi "+ p.name)
p.name = "Pelle"
println("Hi "+ p.name)
```

This is all well and good, but what if Person is immutable?

```
class Person(private val _name: String) {
  def name = "Mr " + _name
  def whatHereName(newName: String): Person = new Person(newName)
}

val p = new Person("Olle")
println("Hi "+ p.name)
val p2 = p.whatHereName("Pelle")
println("Hi "+ p2.name)
```

What should `whatHereName` be called?

**EDIT:** 
I need to put stuff in the "setter" method, like this:

```
class Person(private val _name: String) {
  def name = "Mr " + _name
  def whatHereName(newName: String): Person = {
    if(name.length > 3)
      new Person(newName.capitalize)
    else
      throw new Exception("Invalid new name")
  }
}
```

The real code is much bigger than this, so a simple call to the `copy` method will not do.

**EDIT 2:**

Since there are so many comments on my faked example (that it is incorrect) I better give you the [link](http://github.com/ollekullberg/ScalaLand/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/programmera/scalaland_immutable3/Avatar.scala) to the real class (`Avatar`).

The "setter" methods I don't know what to call are `updateStrength`, `updateWisdom` ... but I will probably change that to `withStrength` soon..

Comment: Did you have a look at http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/ScalaStyleGuide.pdf 3.4.1 Accessors/Mutators

Comment: +100 @oluies THANK YOU! This document will be my bible from now on.

Comment: So, you settled with 'with' :) Looks pretty good when object state update is the only thing happening here. But what if this 'update' action has side effect. Lets say it is an immutable ActiveRecord object, and 'muttator' updates database state and returns new immutable instance. Does 'with' look logical in this case too? What do you think?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like the jodatime way. that would be withName.

```
val p = new Person("Olle")
val p2 = p.withName("kalle");
```

more jodatime examples: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Cool thing. It's just that "with" makes me think about the with keyword used for mixin.

Answer (score 10):

Scala case classes have autogenerated method *copy* for this purpose. It's used like this:

`val p2 = p.copy(name = "Pelle")`

Comment: The "setter" method should probably use the copy method internally. But the "setter" method might do more than just set the value, it could include logic that validates the new name.

Comment: You asked about convention, so existing widely used method is a good example of how it can be done. You can write your own copy method with your own validation and it will look familiar to those who use case classes.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to perform validation, etc. when 'modifying' a field, then **why should this be any different from validation when you first create the object**?

In this case, you can then put the necessary validation/error-throwing logic in the constructor of a case class, and this will be used whenever a new instance is created via the `copy` method.

Comment: You are correct @Kevin, but the example above is not at all what my real code looks like (sorry about that). In my code all "setters" are not doing validation, they are calling a common utility method that takes care of instance creation. In my code i can not use copy since I have to mixin traits.

Comment: @Kevin I updated the question with a link to the real code. It is a complex immutable object. I you have time to take a look I would be glad.

Comment: Those mixins are just going to cause you more pain as time goes by.  You should absolutely be favouring composition instead of inheritance here; Your code seems to be saying that an Avatar is-a Profession and is-a Race, this is false, an Avatar has-a Profession and has-a Race.  Encode the fundamental concepts correctly and everything else should then fall into place much more easily and naturally.

Comment: @Kevin For the mutable object situation it is quite nice to have the Avatar "being" a creature (i.e. being a Dwarf) and "being" a professional (i.e. being a Thief), see http://bit.ly/bwDO1B. The reason Java favors composition for this case is IMHO the lack of multiple inheritance. For the immutable object situation this is, as you say, not very easy to do with traits in Scala. So the solution based on composition looks tempting. Or? Let me know if you reject the mutable solution too..

Comment: The basic idea doesn't just come from lack of multiple inheritance (though this was doubtless a motivating force), you can see this by looking how design style has moved to favouring composition in C++.  Current thinking is to reduce coupling as much as possible.  This helps with unit testing, it also works very nicely with immutability - allowing composed immutable objects to be easily updated via something like the `copy` method available on case classes.  And yes, I'd also advise you to favour immutable objects :)

Comment: @Kevin I am not sure that composition will reduce coupling very much for my code. If I use composition in my code, then Avatar would "have" a profession and "have" a race. But the profession class needs to have a reference back to Avatar to access the fields. Is this "double dependency" still called composition? In any case, Profession can not be tested in isolation.

Comment: @Kevin Multiple inheritance does not work very well in C++, C++ does not have a good solution for the diamond problem. Scala is a different beast, so I think multiple inheritance can be used (if it feels "right" for the actual problem). My aim for the example I am working on is to explore how multiple inheritance works in Scala.

Comment: From what I can see, all the coupling is via strength/charisma/etc.  Why not pull these qualities out into a dedicated (immutable) `Stats` class that can be passed in and out of functions.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a single method for that. Either `copy`, or, in case it is already a case class, `with`:

```
class Person(private val _name: String) {
  def name = "Mr " + _name
  def copy(name: String = _name): Person = new Person(name)
}
```

**EDIT**

The `copy` method on the linked example should look like this:

```
// Setters
def copy(strength: Int = features.strength,
         wisdom: Int = features.wisdom,
         charisma: Int = features.charisma,
         hitpoints: Int = features.hitpoints): Avatar = {
  if (hitpoints != features.hitpoints)
    println("setHitpoints() old value: " + features.hitpoints + ", new value: " + hitpoints)

  if (hitpoints > 0) 
    updateCreatureFeature(
      features.copy(strength = strength,
                    wisdom = wisdom,
                    charisma = charisma,
                    hitpoints = hitpoints))
  else
    throw new DeathException(name + " died!")

  // Alternate coding (depend on thrown exception on "check"):
  // check(strength, wisdom, charisma, hitpoints)
  // updateCreateFeature(...)
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with a link to the real code. It is a complex immutable object.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I see now that the copy strategy works for my code.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Oleg answer, you would write the class like this:

```
case class Person(name: String) //That's all!
```

You would use it like this:

```
val p = Person("Olle") // No "new" necessary
println("Hi" + p.name)
val p2 = p.copy(name="Pelle")
println("Hi" + p2.name)
```

Using the copy method like above is possible, but in your simple case I would just use:

```
val p2 = Person("Pelle")
```

The copy methods show their strengths if you have classes like:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, email: EMail, pets: List[Pet] = List())
val joe = Person("Joe", 41, EMail("joe@example.com"))
val joeAfterHisNextBirthday = joe.copy(age=42)
```

Comment: Thanks @soc, but this is not really what I am looking for. My example above is a much simplified version of the real problem. In my real example I do need a "setter"-like method, that wraps the copy-method. And the question is: What should it be called.

Answer (score 1):

As for now I am using `update<Field>` name convention for all "setter"-like methods on immutable objects.

I can not use `set<Field>` since it reminds too much about the mutable setters in Java.

How do you feel about using `update<Field>` for all methods that returns a new instance of the same identity as the current instance?

Comment: That sounds ok, although I prefer with<Field> a tiny bit.

Comment: If you're following other Scala conventions (especially with the collections library), then you should prefer 'updated' over 'update'. 'update' still suggests a mutating operation.  Having said all that, I still favour 'with'

Comment: Well then "with" it is! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Though previous answers resolve the problem, I would like to share how I deal with immutable objects (which is only syntactic sugar).

To have a clearer syntax (IMHO) I implement the `apply` method in immutable classes, returning the result of the `copy` method in case classes and a new instance when it is a regular class. ie:

```scala
import java.util.Date

class Tournament (val name: String, val start: Date) {
  /* With case class
  def apply (name: String = this.name, start: Date = this.start) =
    copy (name, start)
  */

  def apply (name: String = this.name, start: Date = this.start) =
    new Tournament (name, start)

  override def toString () = s"${name} at ${start}"
}

object Main extends App {
  val tour = new Tournament ("Euroleague", new Date)
  val tour2 = tour (name = tour.name + " 2014")
  println (tour)
  println (tour2)
}
```

This makes the "mutator" method the default method for any instance of that class.